# Passing data from one application another application in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, httprequest, android-broadcast

I am developing two applications. Let the first app be APP1 and second app be APP2. Now in APP1 I am not providing any user permission like INTERNET permission but it will send any http url like http://www.google.com to my second APP2 which will contain user permission like INTERNET. Http request will be send to APP2 from APP1 and  APP2 will response the request and then the result will be send back to APP1 . Finally APP1 contain a webview to show the result. I tried with intent using package manager but not able to pass url to APP2. I am struggling from last two days. Please help me and make understand by giving some examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use content providers. You need to develop your own provider if you  intend to share your data with other applications

Comment: @Raghunandan this two application is developed by me and I am not sharing my data here. If I am not wrong Content provider is used to share data to another application but I am passing my data not sharing. Second application should be in background it will fetch the data, do the work and pass back to first application.

Comment: i don't know what you r asking is possible or not can't comment on that. i guess what you need is a service to get the data from server and then notify and update ui based on the update received. if this comment does not help ignore it.

Comment: @Raghunandan how to pass a simple url or text from one application to another.If you provide me an example it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need INTERNET Permission, please take a lokk at that : 
[Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)  and [Send data to other applications](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Google as implemented an easy way to do this : Intent. You juste have to call your target class to putextras on your Intent to pass data.

Comment: this two application is developed by me and I am not sharing my data here. If I am not wrong Content provider is used to share data to another application but I am passing my data not sharing. Second application should be in background it will fetch the data, do the work and pass back to first application.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at one of Android's IPC mechanisms called Binder:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html
http://www.slideshare.net/jserv/android-ipc-mechanism

Comment: why? wouldn't it be possible to connect these two apps by binder, and send the url and response as parcel?